# Remote client trying to connect to vsftpd in CentoOS returning Connection refused

Tags: iptables, centos6, ftp

I'm trying to [configure the ftp service](http://ethernuno.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/backup-your-configs-and-ios-building-your-tftp-server/) in my server. Everything seems in place, but the client always gets this response: **Connection refused**.

This is the content of my iptables file

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jun  4 17:43:03 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:412]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun  4 17:43:03 2013
```

In case you need it, this it what **iptables -L** returns:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:mysql state ESTABLISHED
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the iptables, although i could be wrong. I followed every step in [this tutorial](http://ethernuno.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/backup-your-configs-and-ios-building-your-tftp-server/). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the ACCEPT for the ftp above the REJECT all. Specifically this line

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

needs to go above this line

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

in your `/etc/syconfig/iptables` file as per the documentation you're following.

Comment: that solved the issue, didn't notice the order. thanks!